# Mongodb $ (dollar sign) project query for arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following data:

```
{
_id: "1"
transitions: [
    {
       "_id" : "11"
      "name" : "Tr1"
      "checkLists" : [
                           { _id: "111", name: "N1"},
                           { _id: "112", name: "N2"}
                           ]
     }  
  ]
}
```

I used the following code to get the name N2 by query of _id:112

```
db.collection.findOne({ 'transitions.checkLists._id: new ObjectId("112") } }}, {  'transitions.checkLists.$': 1 })
```

but the result returns back both of them:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("1"),
  transitions: 
   [ { checkLists: 
        [ { name: 'N1', _id: ObjectId("111") },
          { name: 'N2', _id: ObjectId("112") } ] } ] }
```

I would like to find and get only the name N2 by query of _id:112
Expected Result:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("1"),
  transitions: 
   [ { checkLists: 
        [ { name: 'N2', _id: ObjectId("112") } ] } ] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via the aggregation framework as follow:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 $match: {
  "transitions.checkLists._id": "111"
  }
},
{
"$addFields": {
  "transitions": {
    "$map": {
      "input": "$transitions",
      "as": "t",
      "in": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$$t",
          {
            "checkLists": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$$t.checkLists",
                "as": "c",
                "cond": {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$c._id",
                    "111"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
   }
  }
 },
 {
  "$addFields": {
    transitions: {
     $filter: {
      input: "$transitions",
      as: "elem",
      cond: {
        "$ne": [
          "$$elem.checkLists",
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  }
 }
}

])
```

Explained:

1. Match the transitions.checkLists._id element in first stage.
2. Map/mergeobjects with filtered checklists to filter only the needed object from the transitions.checkLists array.
3. Remove the transitions elements where no checkList exists.
   ( this need to be done to remove elements for same document where there is no matching _id's )

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/u5rzl6MO4wG)

Comment: Thanks for your solution, may I know why {transitions.checkLists.$:1} is not working?

Comment: with $ sign in find/project  in nested arrays of objects  you may filter only up to  level-1 array... , example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/NNBxPs8hxO8